# how to store subItems of listView in an new array

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

this is my listView in xml file`

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

this where data is entered in ListView

```
 ListView petListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    //attach empty view
    View emptyView = findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
    petListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
    //no pet data yet so cursor is set to null
    mCursorAdapter = new PetCursorAdapter(this, null);
    petListView.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);
```

in subitem of my listView there are phone numbers, I want to copy all the phone number in listView to a new Array.

Comment: Why not just iterate through the cursor that feeds the listview and build the array from that?

Comment: @MikeT I don't know how to do that can you give me an example